# What is the purpose of 'framebuffer' when setting up a GL context?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, x11, glx

In [this example code](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial%3a_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_%28GLX%29) it deals with framebuffers before setting up the context.

I've read the man pages of the functions, but I still don't understand exactly what's going on.

So my question is, **what exactly is a framebuffer in GLX and how significant is configuring it**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A framebuffer is an area of memory that holds a displayable image.  You need one when creating an OpenGL context so that OpenGL has a place to store the image it renders.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, although what about the configuration?

Comment: @Pubby: The configuration tells GLX what kind of colours you'd like to draw on it, if you want it to be compositable (transparency effects) etc. Setting up a framebuffer is like an artist preparing his canvas.